# Return a Sum of values from multiple sheets

Tags: excel

I have an excel formula to return values from multiple worksheets and provide the sum of said values. My worksheets vary in year. My formula does not work if the vehicle model does not have a sheet for every year that included in my "Year" list. Many posts on here are similar, but their solutions don't seem to work for me.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'" & C24 & Year & "*'!B:B"),C4,INDIRECT("'" & C24 & Year & "*'!Z:Z")))
```

Not every vehicle has a sheet for every year. How can I make it return a value for the years it does have instead of getting a reference error?

Comment: Have you tried with a simple `IFERROR`? `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&C24&Year&"*'!B:B"),C4,INDIRECT("'"&C24&Year&"*'!Z:Z")),0))` This may required committing with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` in older versions of Excel.

Comment: "My formula does not work if the vehicle model does have a sheet for every year that included in my "Year" list" "Does" or "does not" ?

Comment: @SolarMike Apologies, Formula DOES NOT work for a vehicle model that DOES NOT have a sheet for each year in my "Year" list.

Comment: Then edit the question so it is clear.

Comment: @JosWoolley That formula does seem to work, BUT It requires me to put a space after the text in C24 to correctly match the sheet name.

Comment: I have just tried playing with `=SUM('*'!A1)` for calculating the sum of all cells "A1"in all worksheets, but the results are horrible: the formula does not take the current sheet into account, the formula gets translated into something else and if you start moving pages around, the whole formula messes up. This is definitively a very good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&C24&" "&Year&"*'!B:B"),C4,INDIRECT("'"&C24&" "&Year&"*'!Z:Z")),0))
```

This is the complete formula that works for my instance. Thank you for the help